# VUE JS Observer is an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await

I'm getting an empty array from Observer, I have no idea how can i receive the data.
When the code is finished to run i can see on console log the Observer.
But i need to get the Observer during the addModel so it will not be undefined

```
addModel(modelId, options = {}) {
    if (!this._containerElement) {
      return;
    }
    const model = this.viewer.scene.models[modelId];
    if (!model) {
      throw "Model not found: " + modelId;
    }
    debugger;
    // this.viewer.metaScene.metaModels - is undefined because of empty Array.
    const metaModel = this.viewer.metaScene.metaModels[modelId];
    if (!metaModel) {
      this.error("MetaModel not found: " + modelId);
      return;
    }
    if (this._modelTreeViews[modelId]) {
      this.warn("Model already added: " + modelId);
      return;
    }

    debugger;

    this._modelTreeViews[modelId] = new ModelTreeView(
      this.viewer,
      this,
      model,
      metaModel,
      {
        containerElement: this._containerElement,
        autoExpandDepth: this._autoExpandDepth,
        hierarchy: this._hierarchy,
        sortNodes: this._sortNodes,
        pruneEmptyNodes: this._pruneEmptyNodes,
        rootName: options.rootName
      }
    );
    model.on("destroyed", () => {
      this.removeModel(model.id);
    });
  }
```

Issue:

```
_ob__: Observer
dep: Dep {id: 65896, subs: Array(0)}
value: {__ob__: Observer}
vmCount: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You haven't shown where data is being loaded into the property. The fact that it does happen somewhere, sometime is not enough information for anyone to help you

Comment: source code https://github.com/xeokit/xeokit-sdk/blob/master/src/plugins/TreeViewPlugin/TreeViewPlugin.js

i have copied all there source code into a different folder, and i'm adding my own functionality into it

Comment: You haven't shown how you integrated their SDK with your Vue app

Comment: just copied all the files from node models and then i did import to gtlf plugin from my folder and the same thing with treeview plugin and then i followd there guidelines.

Comment: Is `viewer` accessible in your Vue app?  If so, please edit your question to post the code in the Vue app where you intend to use it.  If not, it seems this question has nothing to do with Vue

Comment: public static setViewer(main_canvas_container: Element): Viewer{
        this.viewer = new Viewer({
            canvasId: main_canvas_container.id,
            transparent: true
        });
        return this.viewer;
    }

Comment: i need to triggers the Observer and get the data that i need and the i need to call the addModel function but i can't do it if i'm getting _ob__: Observer
dep: Dep {id: 65896, subs: Array(0)}
value: {__ob__: Observer}
vmCount: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
from this.viewer.metaScene.metaModels